# Node,exe not found despite correct environment variables CI build windows

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, yarnpkg

I'm dealing with a strange issue. When `yarn install` is ran during my automated CI build, I get the following error:

```
error C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\6sT6aNYk\0\[redacted]\node_modules\fibers: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node build.js || nodejs build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\6sT6aNYk\0\[redacted]\node_modules\fibers
Output:
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My environment variables are correct. I've manually browsed to the directory, and executed the same command using powershell. Then the command does not fail, and node is found in its installation directory. Powershell is the runner configured for this system/project.

During the CI build I can *See* node.exe spawning under gitlabrunner.exe. So the path for the process is correct. It's just `yarn install` that fails to find node.exe.

I'm not a javascript developer, and I do not know how to dive deeper into what is happening. How can I see what causes this problem? Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Other things I've looked at:

- path length disabled
- Building from other directories in the system (manually, it all works)
- Removing node & npm and re-installing

Edit:

The issue also occurs if I use npm install instead of yarn install.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Another item in my build chain was adding items to the path in a loop. previously this was not a problem, but maybe an update added more items.

The solution was to clear the environment and add the original path back.